# O que incluir entre os `acentos graves`?

Tags: suporte

Estava fazendo algumas edições hoje e fiquei na dúvida do que exatamente deve ser incluído entre os acentos graves, gerando `esta formatação`. Fiz uma pesquisa na ajuda, mas não achei nada específico, apenas sobre a utilização deste recurso em comentários, mas não onde exatamente deve ser usado.

Por exemplo, os termos que se referem à linguagem (`php,` `java`, `c#`) devem ser sempre formatados com os acentos graves? E os nomes de arquivos (`index.php`, `script.js`)? Nomes de funções (`echo`, `function`) e pequenos trechos de códigos que são inseridos no corpo do texto acho que sim né? O que mais? O que não? Exemplos? Dicas? Uma página da ajuda que não achei? Uma pergunta idêntica que (de novo) não achei? :-)

Comment: Relacionado: guia de estilo [como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/91) tem algumas recomendaçãos(não regras) sobre quando usar determinados recursos.

Comment: Ah valeu mesmo, solucionou não só esta dúvida como algumas outras! :) De acordo com o que consta nesta reposta que vc linkou, apenas os termos que se referem à linguagem (php, java etc) acho que estão fora né. Acho que só quando for pra linkar no wiki da tag...

Comment: Na verdade os links para tags são formatadas automaticamente ao se fazer assim: `[meta-tag:debate]` ou `[tag:c]`. Nos comentário não funciona, só em publicações. Faça um teste para ver como que fica.

Comment: @Math Já tava até utilizando demais. :P

Comment: @gustavox hahaha.. no começo a gente empolga msm :P Acho que esse tipo de formatação costuma ser mais comum aqui no meta, igual eu usei ele [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2722/3117) ou [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2668/3117), não me lembro de um caso de alguém usando no site principal.

Comment: @Math Então, vi os exemplos que vc postou, mas tava pensando aqui, e acho que no site principal pode ser interessante postar a tag numa resposta, quando a pergunta procura por referências sobre um assunto (dei uma olhada e algumas wikis são muito boas mesmo), mas acho que só na resposta mesmo, porque editar a pergunta incluindo a tag fica meio sem sentido, porque não haveria informação de que a tag contém informações (mas que fica esteticamente bonito fica rsrs).